# Unity setting GUIText of another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have (PlanetController):

```
private GameController gameController;
...
void OnMouseEnter()
{
    gameController.setClassText("Orbital speed: " + orbitSpeed);
}
```

In the GameController script:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {
public GUIText classText;
void Start () {
    this.setClassText ("");
}

public void setClassText(string text) {
    classText.text = text;
}
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlanetController.OnMouseEnter () (at Assets/scripts/PlanetController.cs:29)
```

The text object is assigned correctly in the inspector so I am at a lost as to what is wrong.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `gameController` set?

Comment: @Chris I added gameController = GetComponent<GameController> (); to the start method of my PlanetController, but I still get the same error.

Comment: what is on Assets/scripts/PlanetController.cs:29? is that the OnMouseEnter() ? and what object is null? gameController or orbitSpeed or classText ?

Comment: @JinJi gameController.setClassText("Orbital speed: " + orbitSpeed); orbitSpeed is not the problem as I can do gameController.setClassText("Orbital speed: "); and still get the issue.

Comment: is gameController or classText null? does this happen as soon as you run the game or when your reload your level / pause & resume your debugger?

Comment: @JinJi gameController is printing out as null :(

Comment: does this happen as soon as you run the game or when your reload your level / pause & resume your debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have

```
gameController = GetComponent<GameController> ();
```

make sure that PlanetController and GameController are actually on the same game object in your scene. if they are not, you will have to use:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html

Comment: Hmm they are indeed not, I will have a fiddle and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks man, I fixed it with: 'void Start () {
  gameController = FindObjectOfType (typeof(GameController)) as GameController;
 }' in my PlanetController script.